# conversion NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c

How to convert from `NSMutableData` to `NSMutableArray`?

```
 NSMutableData * webData=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:self.sendRequestCompains];


- (NSMutableData *)sendRequestCompains{

    NSMutableString *sRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<getCOMPAINs xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/PlatformService/method\">"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<Id_USR>"];    // any attribute
    [sRequest appendString:@"1"];    // attribute value
    [sRequest appendString:@"</Id_USR>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</getCOMPAINs>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Envelope>"];


    NSURL   *ServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.29.7.2/server_comp.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:ServiceURL];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset:UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://10.29.7.2/server_comp.php/getCOMPAINs" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        myMutableData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"Connection success");
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        NSError *WSerror;
        NSURLResponse *WSresponse;

    myMutableData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
        NSLog(@"slt%d",[myMutableData length]);
    }

    return myMutableData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data come from your web server through NSURLConnection, I would suggest converting it to an NSString and inspecting its structure:

```
NSString* dataStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"DATA: $@", dataStr);
```

You will possibly need to parse the result in some way (line by line?) and build the array that way.

If you provide the output, it will possible to help you further.

OLD:

If the `NSData` object was originally an array encoded through `NSKeyedArchiver`, you can try with ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSKeyedUnarchiver)):

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:webData];
```

Otherwise, please specify where this `NSData` object comes from and how it was created.

Comment: i recive webdata from my server

Comment: because this is the format of the response your server sends back; the string may encode an array, but it will be in any case a string. If you inspect the string you can understand what needs to be done to build the array...